# Integrate react-native-navigation V2 with redux

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

In version 1 of RNNavigation, I was sending my store to each screen by this way.

```
Navigation.registerComponent(RouterConstants.SplashScreen, () => SplashScreen, store, Provider)
```

But in V2 it seems it's not working.
[image]

**EDIT:**

index.js:

```
import configureNavigation from './routers/app_navigation'
import createStore from './reducers'

const store = createStore()
configureNavigation(store, Provider)

class App extends React.Component {
 constructor (props) {
   super(props)
   .
   .
   .
   this.startApp()
 }

 startApp () {
  Navigation.setRoot({
    stack: {
      children: [{
        component: {
          name: RouterConstants.SplashScreen
        }
      }]
    }
  })
 }
}

const app = new App()
```

app_navigation.js:

```
import SplashScreen from '../containers/splash_screen_container'
.....
...


const initializeRouter = (store, Provider) => {
    Navigation.registerComponent(RouterConstants.SplashScreen, () => SplashScreen, store, Provider)
    ....
    ..

}
export default initializeRouter
```

Comment: Can you add the code for the navigation setup and also the store?

Comment: Ideally it would be text, not an image, but that's better than nothing. Now, I find a lot of results for terms in that error here on SO. Did you see any of them? If so, do they not resolve your problem too? If not, then as Pritish said, you should post the full code needed to understand the error, as we don't know what those variables are just by looking at that 1 line.

Comment: @underscore_d I just added some more codes

Comment: I am getting an error like 'Application has not been registered.'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like you can't register to the provider the old way.

Therefore as a workaround, you can create a `HOC`, *that wraps the screen to the provider*

**Definition**

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

...

function reduxStoreWrapper (MyComponent, store) {
    return () => {
        return class StoreWrapper extends React.Component {
            render () {
                return (
                    <Provider store={store}>
                        <MyComponent />
                    </Provider>
                );
            }
        };
    };
}
```

**Usage**

```
Navigation.registerComponent("RouterConstants.SplashScreen", reduxStoreWrapper(SplashScreen, store))
```

Comment: Hi, is anyone getting this error? - undefined is not a function (evaluating'(0,_reduxStoreWrapper2.default)(_LoginForm2.default, store)')

Comment: It would be great if you could post a question for the issue with relevant details so that users will be able to identify the problem clearly. Thanks

Comment: What if I have to register 3 screens? Should I create 3 `function reduxStoreWrapper`... ?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, thanks Pritish for the solution, but building on the above solution, caused an error for me:

> undefined is not a function (evaluating'(0,_withReduxStoreWrapper2.default)(_LoginForm2.default, store)'

I modified `Navigation.registerComponent()` to ***return a function*** in the 2nd argument, instead of calling it:

```
export function registerScreens() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));
    Navigation.registerComponent('LoginForm', () => withReduxStoreWrapper(LoginForm, store));
}
```

Here is my modified HOC too:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const withReduxStoreWrapper = (MyComponent, store) =>
    class StoreWrapper extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <MyComponent />
                </Provider>
            );
        }
    };

export default withReduxStoreWrapper;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Defining a Redux store wrapper HOC**

A slightly more compact way using an arrow function:

```
// withReduxStoreWrapper.js
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const withReduxStoreWrapper = (ReduxScreen, reduxStore) => () => (props) => (
  <Provider store={reduxStore}>
    <ReduxScreen {...props} />
  </Provider>
);

export default withReduxStoreWrapper;
```

**Registering the screens**

You can then register the screen as follow:

```
// index.js
// ...

const registerScreens = (store) => {
  Navigation.registerComponent('MyReduxScreen', withReduxStoreWrapper(MyReduxScreen, store));
  Navigation.registerComponent('MyNormalScreen', () => MyNormalScreen);
}

const store = configureStore();
registerScreens(store);
```